# Loop backwards Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, indexing

I would like to loop backwards in a array in javascript and then get the index of each element in the array for example if a array has 10 elements and  is looped backwards it would log 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0. for some werid reason i am getting a bunch of negaitive -1s and im confused why it wont just return the index properly.

here is the code

```
//Arrays I would like to pass into the function

const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];

function validateCred(arr) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(arr.indexOf(i));
    }
}

console.log(validateCred(valid1));
```

Comment: Why are you calling `arr.indexOf(i)` if you really want to log `i`?

Comment: i am trying to log the index of each element to see the index because i am trying to use their indexes

Comment: But the index is `i`, not `arr.indexOf(i)`. `arr.indexOf(i)` looks for an element with value `i` in the array and returns its index. That is absolutely not what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

why `-1`s?

It is because of `arr.indexOf(i)` when the loop starts `i=15` so:

`arr.indexOf(15)` will return `-1` because you don't have a `15` in your array.

next `i=14` same as above.

.
.
.

`i=9` then it will find the element at index `3`.

Answer (score 1):

As UnholySheep explains above, Array.indexOf(i) gives you the index of the first occurrence of the value represented by i in the array. Here is some code to help you debug:

```
function validateCred(arr) {
  let sum = 0
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(i)        // log the index
    console.log(arr[i])   // log the value
  }
}
```